# How to draw $T$-$S$ diagrams?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

I am having a bit of trouble visualising how to go, say, from a $p$-$V$ diagram for the cycle of a gas, into a $T$-$S$ diagram for the same process. In class, we studied four main types of transformations:

- **Adiabatic**: for which $Q = 0$, so here the entropy would remain constant by definition (vertical line in $T$-$S$ diagram).
- **Isothermal**: for which $T =$ constant, so we would get a horizontal line in the $T$-$S$ diagram.
- **Isobaric**: for which $p =$ constant
- **Isochoric**: for which $V =$ constant

For these last two cases, how can I draw the diagram?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should use $dS = \delta Q/T$ and $\delta Q = mc_{v \text{ or } p} dT$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment:

You're looking for the paths in the $TS$ space for *reversible* isochoric and isobaric processes. It's important to specify they're reversible. For reversible processes, $dS = \delta Q /T$, where I use $\delta$ and not $d$ because infinitesimal heat is not an exact differential (i.e. it's not the *change* of any quantity).

Anyway. For an isochoric process, work is null, and $\delta Q = mc_v dT$. Dividing by $T$,
$$ dS = mc_v \frac{dT}{T}.$$
In integral form,
$$\Delta S_{12} = mc_v\int_{T_1}^{T_2}\frac{dT}{T} = mc_v \log(T_2/T_1).$$

This associates your entropy variation with your temperature variation in an isochoric. If you keep $T_1$ fixed and vary $T_2$, you get your curve. For the isobaric, use $c_p$.

Comment: Bzazz For isobaric, why you say we use $c_p$? We do have $\delta q = dU - \delta w$, where $dU = nc_v dT$ and $\delta w = pdV$? Thanks!

Comment: Oh I think I got it, by definition of $q$ in isobaric process, $q=nc_p \Delta T$

Comment: By definition of $c_p$ rather than of isobaric. But yeah.

Comment: @Bzazz can you elaborate a bit more on why infinitesmal heat is not an exact differential?

Comment: That's a different question :P